# how to set notification icon in above lollipop version like facebook

Tags: android, push-notification

My java code:I am using below code but its not working.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, LiveFeedScreen.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    final int not_nu = generateRandom();
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            not_nu, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notificationbig_icon)
            .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.header_blue))
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(mMessage)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setStyle(
                    new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(mMessage))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(not_nu, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Its working only below lollipop but image its showing very small.

Comment: Is it simply the case of the image resolution not being of an appropriate size? Compare it on different devices and check if the size of the image is consistent or not.

Comment: check it according your requirement.<http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-custom-notification-tutorial/>

Comment: set your ic_launcher to icon if it is the same. .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))

Answer (score 0):

could you try below one:   ` private void Notify(String notificationMessage, String pushFullMessage) {

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GCMNotificationActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("pushNotification", pushFullMessage);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    final int not_nu = generateRandom();
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            not_nu, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


    android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo) //Small Icon from drawable
            .setContentTitle(this.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(notificationMessage)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLocalOnly(true)
            .setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.green))
            .setStyle(
                    new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(notificationMessage))
```

//                .setLargeIcon(
//                        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
//                                R.drawable.ic_launcher)) //Big Icon from drawable
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

```
    notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
    notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{0, 100, 200, 300});

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(not_nu, notificationBuilder.build());
}

public static int generateRandom() {
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Its a known problem from Android L, what you have to do is pretty simple

Check device OS version during runtime and

if its below Lollipop use the method which you are already using,

else if its above Lollipop create a new silhouette icon and use it instead of your `notificationbig_icon`